# Timeout issue with cloudfare while uploading large size images greater than 300Kb (Approx)

Tags: php, cloudflare, plesk, web-development-server

I have multiple websites hosted in plesk onyx server. Some of them are connected to cloudflare free version. The websites were working great until recently when I am having problem with uploading large size image files, greater than 300Kb approximately, which are not exactly pretty large.I get an 524 timeout error after 60 seconds. **The upload of files works when I set the A and AAAA records of the website to bypass Cloudflare.(in cloudfare dashboard)**

**Note:** There's no problem with php code. Also, I cannot forever set A and AAAA records to bypass cloudflare because I get 404 not found Error when sharing posts on my website to facebook. I don't know what's the problem but Facebook cannot scrape my website.

I am not expert in working with server, but I have tried increasing max_execution_time in php.ini file, which fails.Also, there's sufficient  maximum file upload size. Is this because of Free version of cloudflare? I don't understand the root of the problem

Comment: How slow is your internet connection and/or server? Nginx/Apache can issue timeouts, and CloudFlare won't wait more than 100 seconds, so if you're on dialup...

Comment: The 404 from Facebook probably indicates other stuff seriously wrong with your setup. You might be fixing symptoms instead of the cause here.

Comment: @ceejayoz The internet is pretty fast [30 Mb/sec]. The upload works when I remove A and AAAA records from cloudflare. 404 Facebook error is solved when A and AAAA records are added back. But image uploading again gives 524 error. I must be doing something wrong with cloudflare.

Comment: I guess so, because I don't understand the cause.

Comment: I'd start by working the 404 error. Have you put your URL into https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?

Comment: Maybe 404 is not relevant. Because the main issue here is with uploading large images. I had my site connected to cloudflare for almost 2 years, everything's working perfect, until few days back, when large size images couldnot be uploaded anymore.

Comment: Same problem. Uploading huge HD images and 4K videos so we can't use CloudFlare anymore. Kind of stupid if you ask me.